# Can JOSSO meet this requirement?

Tags: single-sign-on, josso

We have multiple application servers and with different applications, for ex: server1 has app1, server2 has app2 etc..I am looking to implement JOSSO for single sign on for these applications. Question is, can JOSSO support this kind of architecture? or if not are there any other open source single sing on APIs avaialable(in java/j2ee) for this requirement?

Comment: What is your authentication source of reference? If you have MS-Active Directory or something similar it may meet your needs.

Comment: We are using LDAP. Have you used JOSSO2?. How did you configure execution environment if it sits on different machine than service provide machine? Manually or using web-console? or is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

In my company I implement Josso with this kind of architecture. We have may be 5 servers with more or less 10 applications and the authentication is entirely managed with JOSSO. Most of our applications use ASP MVC .Net, so I had to write an agent (embedded in the client application) for this, because Josso doesn't provides ones. But the central JOSSO gateway runs as a tomcat servlet on an independant server.

So, yes it supports this kind oif architecture. We use josso 1.8 for two years now, and then I tweak it to fit some requirements. We didn't upgrade to josso 2 because I don't think they is any new extradinary new features.

It exists other open source, have a look at CAS: http://www.jasig.org/cas which is really close to josso implementation, but may be better.